# jmeter: AbstractJavaSamplerClient - Do setUpTest only once for all threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jmeter

I am developing a Java Request Sampler with JMeter by extending  [AbstractJavaSamplerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/AbstractJavaSamplerClient.html). The test goes like this:

```
public class JmeterTest extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {
    public void setupTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
       System.out.println("Test setup");
    }

    public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
        SampleResult result = new SampleResult();
        System.out.println("Test..");
        result.setSuccessful(true);
        result.setResponseData("Success");
    }

    public void teardownTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
       System.out.println("Test cleanup");
    }
}
```

I created a jar out of this test class and pointed it through the JMeter UI (through Java Request Sampler). The problem in my case is when I run the test with `5 users`, **the setUpTest & tearDownTest methods** gets called for every user as per design.

Is there any setting where the setUp and Cleanup methods get called only once for all threads in the thread group. My requirement is to **do setup and cleanup only once for all threads**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the options you can try out:

1. Perform setUp actions separately in [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group)
2. Perform setUp actions separately in the same Thread Group. Put setUp logic under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) and use `${__BeanShell(vars.getIteration() == 1)}` as condition
3. Modify your code like:

   ```
   public void setupTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
      if (JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables().getIteration() == 1) {
          System.out.println("Test setup");
      }
   }
   ```

Both points 2 and 3 assume that setUp code will be executed only during first iteration of your test by each thread. Remember that [JMeterVariables.getIteration()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getIteration()) number is incremented only when [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)-level loops occur.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Option 1 will solve my problem for now. I will read more about 2 & 3.